# timeword - from one date to another date

Tags: php, date

### Rewritten to be clearer

I have a website that has several exhibits. One exhibit can span over a number of days and sometimes months. In that sense it can also span years (although that's only if it starts in the previous year and ends in the current year like 25th december 2010 to 5th january 2011)

What I need is a function that will take the two dates, and display it in a human readable format with the **least amount** of information required to interpret.

### Some Examples:

So given the dates 18th May 2010 to 19th May 2010, this should be displayed as:
**18 to 19th May 2010.**
Notice here, the first date has the month and year ommitted because they are the same as the final date.

16th April 2011 to 15th May 2011 = 16th April to 15th May 2011
Notice here that the year is omitted, same reason as above.

8th March 2008 to 8th March 2009 = 8th March 2008 to 8th March 2009
Notice here that there is no change because there is a different year we need to display it all.

=============================================================

it just needs to intelligently and helpfully hide the parts of the dates that can be deduced by reading the scentence.

Psuedo for the function:

```
timewordDateFromTo(date1, date2, 'd M Y'){

$showYear = $showMonth = true;
if(year(date1)==year(date2)) 
{
$showYear = false
if(month(date1)==month(date2)) $showMonth = false
}

//do something else here

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this should work, as the other person stated you will need to add some error checking. I assumed you had the dates "15th April 2011" and "18th May 2011" as the inputs. Code could use some cleanup to.

```
function sentenceFromDates($date1, $date2){
$string=false;
$date1= strtotime($date1);
$date2= strtotime($date2);


//first check for years
$year1= date('Y', $date1);
$year2= date('Y', $date2);
$month1= date('n', $date1);
$month2= date('n', $date2);
    //Different years, no change
    if($year2 > $year1)
    {

        $string= date('jS M Y', $date1) . ' to ' . date('jS M Y', $date2);
        return $string;
    }
    //Same year and month
    elseif($month1 == $month2)
    {
        // 15th to 20th May 2011
        $string= date('jS', $date1) . ' to ' . date('jS M Y', $date2);
        return $string;

    }
    //Same year different month
    else
    {
        $string= date('jS M', $date1) . ' to ' . date('jS M Y', $date2);
        return $string;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
function timewordDateFromTo($date1, $date2, $format)
{

    $string = false;
    if($date2 > $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date1) . ' to ' . date($format,$date2);
    }
    elseif($date2 < $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date2) . ' to ' . date($format,$date1);
    }

    return $string;    
}

//Assuming two well formed date strings
function timewordDateFromTo($date1, $date2, $format)
{

    $string = false;
    $date1 = strtotime($date1);
    $date2 = strtotime($date2);

    if($date2 > $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date1) . ' to ' . date($format,$date2);
    }
    elseif($date2 < $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date2) . ' to ' . date($format,$date1);
    }

    return $string;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's see, would be easier to take two timestamps, but either way:

```
//Assuming two timestamps
function timewordDateFromTo($date1, $date2, $format)
{

    $string = false;
    if($date2 > $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date1) . ' to ' . date($format,$date2);
    }
    elseif($date2 < $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date2) . ' to ' . date($format,$date1);
    }

    return $string;    
}

//Assuming two well formed date strings
function timewordDateFromTo($date1, $date2, $format)
{

    $string = false;
    $date1 = strtotime($date1);
    $date2 = strtotime($date2);

    if($date2 > $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date1) . ' to ' . date($format,$date2);
    }
    elseif($date2 < $date1)
    {
         $string = date($format,$date2) . ' to ' . date($format,$date1);
    }

    return $string;    
}
```

Of course, you'd probably want some additional input error checking, but that's the basic skeleton of it.

Comment: +1 for effort, however I think I have failed to explain what I want. I'll add more text to the question